# Python regex to ignore what is between quotes

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string, part of which is surrounded within quotes. Like the one at the third line of the code snippet below. I want the string to be formatted into a dict literal. Meaning wherever the quotes are missing, they should be added. But the part which is within the quotes has to be ignored. I came up with the code below to handle this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from re import sub

str = "key1:[val1,val2,val3],key2:'val4A,val4B'"
str = sub(r"([\w\-\.]+|[\"'].*[\"'])", r"'\1'", f"{{{str}}}")
str = sub(r"[\"']{2,}(.*)[\"']{2,}", r"'\1'", str)
fin = literal_eval(str)
print(fin)
```

This code does the work, but I want to know if there is a way to achieve this with one time usage of sub. Before you mark this as a duplicate, I tried a large number of the solutions provided on the web including positive and negative look ahead and look behind, exclusion, and simple negative match. Couldn't find any which would work. If there is a solution I have missed or anyone has a solutions, I would highly appreciate knowing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `([\w\-\.]+(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$))` :

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UoT3go/2)

Comment: Ah, you are repeating not to avoid other characters. Never thought of that! Thanks.